# Far Cry 4 emblem meaning?

Tags: far-cry-4

What is the emblem in the top right corner of the screen next to the rupees when you're looking at the map? I've looked all over and can't find it but I have noticed that it changes frequently.

Answer (score 5):

Are you referring to the loot bag symbol? The amount of items in your loot bag may differ.

[image]